# SQL Complex Filter + Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following tables.

## Users

```
userID     fullName
5          Mr. Joe
7          Mr. Bean
```

## Supplies

```
id     supplyDesc     isActive
1      Ballpen         1
2      Adhesive Tape   1
3      White Paper     1
```

## SupplyRequests

```
    id  requestCode     forFrom      forTo        userID
    1   SPR-2017-1      12-01-2017   02-28-2018   5
    2   SPR-2017-2      12-01-2017   02-28-2018   7
    3   SPR-2017-3      01-01-2018   03-31-2018   7
```

## SupplyRequestDetails

```
    id  rqID   supplyID  storeID    qty   isActive
    1   1      1         1          1000  1
    2   1      2         1          2000  1
    3   1      1         12         2000  1
    4   1      2         12         3000  1
    5   1      1         13         3000  1
    6   1      2         13         4000  1
    7   2      1         10         100   1
    8   2      2         10         200   1
    9   2      1         11         200   1
    10  2      2         11         300   1
    11  3      1         10         1     1
    12  3      2         10         2     1
    13  3      1         11         2     1
    14  3      2         11         3     1
```

The requirement:

*Fetch all users with their corresponding total quantity of requests per supply item along with the total number of unique branches they requested for, given a date range. Must be an active supply item in request details and supply table.*

**Note**
Supplies may vary from time to time

What I tried so far:

```
declare @forFrom varchar(50) = '12/01/2017'
declare @forTo varchar(50) = '02/28/2018'

declare @cols nvarchar(max), @cols2 nvarchar(max), @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', MAX(' + QUOTENAME(supplyDesc) + ')' + '''' + supplyDesc + ''''
                       FROM (select a.id'supplyID',
                        a.supplyDesc,
                        SUBSTRING(d.fullName, 5, LEN(MAX(d.fullName)))fullName,
                        SUM(CASE WHEN ((CAST(c.forFrom as datetime) >= @forFrom and CAST(c.forTo as datetime) <= @forTo)) THEN b.qty ELSE 0 END)totalQty
                        from Supplies a
                        left join SupplyRequestDetails b
                        on a.id = b.supplyID
                        left join SupplyRequests c
                        on b.rqID = c.id
                        left join Users d
                        on c.userID = d.id
                        where a.isActive = 1
                        or b.isActive = 1
                        group by a.id,
                            a.supplyDesc,
                            fullName
                ) as x
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'');

select @cols2 = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(supplyDesc)
                       FROM (select a.id'supplyID',
                        a.supplyDesc,
                        SUBSTRING(d.fullName, 5, LEN(MAX(d.fullName)))fullName,
                        SUM(CASE WHEN ((CAST(c.forFrom as datetime) >= @forFrom and CAST(c.forTo as datetime) <= @forTo)) THEN b.qty ELSE 0 END)totalQty
                        from Supplies a
                        left join SupplyRequestDetails b
                        on a.id = b.supplyID
                        left join SupplyRequests c
                        on b.rqID = c.id
                        left join Users d
                        on c.userID = d.id
                        where a.isActive = 1
                        or b.isActive = 1
                        group by a.id,
                            a.supplyDesc,
                            fullName
                ) as x
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SET @query = N'
declare @forFrom varchar(50) = ''12/01/2017''
declare @forTo varchar(50) = ''02/28/2018''
SELECT SUBSTRING(fullName, 5, LEN(fullName))fullName, ' + @cols + '
FROM (SELECT SUBSTRING(fullName, 5, LEN(fullName))fullName, ' + @cols + '
FROM (select a.id''supplyID'',
                a.supplyDesc,
                SUBSTRING(d.fullName, 5, LEN(MAX(d.fullName)))fullName,
                        SUM(CASE WHEN ((CAST(c.forFrom as datetime) >= @forFrom and CAST(c.forTo as datetime) <= @forTo)) THEN b.qty ELSE 0 END)totalQty
                from Supplies a
                left join SupplyRequestDetails b
                on a.id = b.supplyID
                left join SupplyRequests c
                on b.rqID = c.id
                left join Users d
                on c.userID = d.id
                where a.isActive = 1
                or b.isActive = 1
                group by a.id,
                    a.supplyDesc,
                    fullName
) as j
PIVOT (
    SUM(totalQty) FOR supplyDesc IN ('
    + @cols2
    + ')

) AS a
WHERE fullName is not null
GROUP BY fullName
ORDER BY fullName;';


PRINT @query
EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

Result is somehow like:

```
fullName     Ballpen        Adhesive Tape     White Paper
Mr.Joe       6303           9505              NULL
```

The expected result set:

```
fullName  uqStores  Ballpen        Adhesive Tape     White Paper
Mr. Joe   3         6000           4000              NULL
Mr. Bean  2         300            500               NULL
```

As you may notice, I first tried to get the list of items from the Supplies table and tried (but failed) to tag each item to users who requested each item respectively within the given conditions (Date range and activity status). Then, created dynamic columns and prepared a pivot of supplies. Also, I have yet to figure out how to count all  the unique storeID's from those queries.

I am thinking the first problem is how I tried to tag the users to each item. Though, not sure how to get them all along with a bunch of items simultaneously.

Your help will be very much appreciated.

EDIT:

I had to fix some queries. I believe I copied wrong items.

Update:

```
fullName      Ballpen      Adhesive Tape      White Paper
Mr. Joe       6000         9000               NULL
Mr. Bean      300          500                NULL
```

PS: Somehow, I was arriving to the solution bit-by-bit. Now I just have to get the unique stores per request.

**Update:**

This seems to work, but really messy.

```
DECLARE @forFrom varchar(50) = '12/01/2017'
DECLARE @forTo varchar(50) = '02/28/2018'

declare @cols nvarchar(max), @cols2 nvarchar(max), @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
    select @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', MAX(' + QUOTENAME(supplyDesc) + ')' + '''' + supplyDesc + ''''
                           FROM (select DISTINCT a.id'supplyID',
                                    a.supplyDesc,
                                    COUNT(CASE WHEN ((CAST(c.forFrom as datetime) >= @forFrom and CAST(c.forTo as datetime) <= @forTo)) THEN b.storeID ELSE NULL END)numberOfStores,
                                    SUBSTRING(d.fullName, 5, LEN(MAX(CASE WHEN (CAST(c.forFrom as datetime) >= @forFrom and CAST(c.forTo as datetime) <= @forTo) THEN d.fullName ELSE NULL END)))fullName,
                                    SUM(CASE WHEN ((CAST(c.forFrom as datetime) >= @forFrom and CAST(c.forTo as datetime) <= @forTo)) THEN b.qty ELSE 0 END)totalQty
                                from Supplies a
                                left join SupplyRequestDetails b
                                on a.id = b.supplyID
                                left join SupplyRequests c
                                on b.rqID = c.id
                                left join Users d
                                on c.userID = d.id
                                where a.isActive = 1
                                or b.isActive = 1
                                group by a.id,
                                    a.supplyDesc,
                                    fullName
                    ) as x
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
            ,1,1,'');
    select @cols2 = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(supplyDesc)
                           FROM (select DISTINCT a.id'supplyID',
                                    a.supplyDesc,
                                    COUNT(CASE WHEN ((CAST(c.forFrom as datetime) >= @forFrom and CAST(c.forTo as datetime) <= @forTo)) THEN b.storeID ELSE NULL END)numberOfStores,
                                    SUBSTRING(d.fullName, 5, LEN(MAX(CASE WHEN (CAST(c.forFrom as datetime) >= @forFrom and CAST(c.forTo as datetime) <= @forTo) THEN d.fullName ELSE NULL END)))fullName,
                                    SUM(CASE WHEN ((CAST(c.forFrom as datetime) >= @forFrom and CAST(c.forTo as datetime) <= @forTo)) THEN b.qty ELSE 0 END)totalQty
                                from Supplies a
                                left join SupplyRequestDetails b
                                on a.id = b.supplyID
                                left join SupplyRequests c
                                on b.rqID = c.id
                                left join Users d
                                on c.userID = d.id
                                where a.isActive = 1
                                or b.isActive = 1
                                group by a.id,
                                    a.supplyDesc,
                                    fullName
                    ) as x
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
            ,1,1,'')

    SET @query = N'
    declare @forFrom varchar(50) = ''' + @forFrom + '''
    declare @forTo varchar(50) = ''' + @forTo + '''
    SELECT SUBSTRING(fullName, 5, LEN(fullName))fullName, COUNT(numberOfStores)numOfStores,' + @cols + '
    FROM (select DISTINCT a.id''supplyID'',
                a.supplyDesc,
                COUNT(CASE WHEN ((CAST(c.forFrom as datetime) >= @forFrom and CAST(c.forTo as datetime) <= @forTo)) THEN b.storeID ELSE NULL END)numberOfStores,
                SUBSTRING(d.fullName, 5, LEN(MAX(CASE WHEN (CAST(c.forFrom as datetime) >= @forFrom and CAST(c.forTo as datetime) <= @forTo) THEN d.fullName ELSE NULL END)))fullName,
                SUM(CASE WHEN ((CAST(c.forFrom as datetime) >= @forFrom and CAST(c.forTo as datetime) <= @forTo)) THEN b.qty ELSE 0 END)totalQty
            from Supplies a
            left join SupplyRequestDetails b
            on a.id = b.supplyID
            left join SupplyRequests c
            on b.rqID = c.id
            left join Users d
            on c.userID = d.id
            where a.isActive = 1
            or b.isActive = 1
            group by a.id,
                a.supplyDesc,
                fullName
    ) as j
    PIVOT (
        SUM(totalQty) FOR supplyDesc IN ('
        + @cols2
        + ')

    ) AS a
    WHERE fullName is not null
    GROUP BY fullName
    ORDER BY fullName;';

    EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

Sure there are better ways to do it. I'd really love your suggestions.

**Update**

Derived and edited from the answer of @sarslan:

```
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        S.supplyDesc 
        , fullName
        , COUNT(DISTINCT storeID) [uqStores]
        , SUM(qty) SumQty   
    FROM 
        Supplies S
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT U.fullName, supplyID, storeID, qty, SRD.isActive FROM SupplyRequestDetails SRD 
                        INNER JOIN SupplyRequests SR ON SRD.rqID = SR.id AND ( SR.forFrom >= @forFrom AND SR.forTo <= @forTo ) 
                        INNER JOIN Users U ON SR.userID = U.userID ) AS ST ON ST.supplyID = S.id
    WHERE ST.isActive = 1
    GROUP BY fullName, supplyDesc 
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT storeID) > 1
) SRC
PIVOT ( SUM (SumQty) FOR supplyDesc IN ( ' + @ColNames + ')) PVT '
```

Say, for example, item with id 1 in SupplyRequestDetails is to be rendered inactive.

Result is:

```
fullName      Ballpen      Adhesive Tape      White Paper
Mr. Bean      5000         NULL               NULL
Mr. Bean      NULL         9000               NULL
Mr. Joe       300          500                NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script.

```
declare @forFrom datetime = '12/01/2017'
declare @forTo datetime = '02/28/2018'

DECLARE @ColNames NVARCHAR(MAX)= ''
SELECT @ColNames = @ColNames + ',' + QUOTENAME (supplyDesc) FROM Supplies WHERE isActive = 1
SET @ColNames = STUFF(@ColNames,1,1,'')

DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        S.supplyDesc 
        , fullName
        , COUNT(DISTINCT storeID) [uqStores]
        , SUM(qty) SumQty   
    FROM 
        Supplies S
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT U.fullName, supplyID, storeID, qty, SRD.isActive FROM SupplyRequestDetails SRD 
                        INNER JOIN SupplyRequests SR ON SRD.rqID = SR.id AND ( SR.forFrom >= @forFrom AND SR.forTo <= @forTo ) 
                        INNER JOIN Users U ON SR.userID = U.userID 
                    WHERE SRD.isActive = 1 ) AS ST ON ST.supplyID = S.id
    WHERE S.isActive = 1 
    GROUP BY fullName, supplyDesc 
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT storeID) > 1
) SRC
PIVOT ( SUM (SumQty) FOR supplyDesc IN ( ' + @ColNames + ')) PVT '


EXEC sp_executesql @Query, N'@forFrom  DATETIME, @forTo DATETIME' , @forFrom = @forFrom, @forTo = @forTo
```

Result:

```
fullName             uqStores    Ballpen     Adhesive Tape White Paper
-------------------- ----------- ----------- ------------- -----------
Mr. Bean             2           300         500           NULL
Mr. Joe              3           6000        9000          NULL
```

Comment: Neat, but i don't think the static declaration of supplyNames would work. The supplies may vary from time to time.

Comment: Also, I had to improvise a dynamic pivot because of the dynamic items.

Comment: I changed to query for dynamic suppliers

Comment: Thanks. Looking at this query makes me think I need to go back to sql fundamentals.

Comment: Oh, we forgot the isActive filter. Here:
`SELECT U.fullName, supplyID, storeID, qty, SRD.isActive FROM Supplies SRD `....
And the where clause,
`WHERE ST.isActive = 1`

Comment: @am0r You have made "isActive" changing before me. Thanks :) I made some addition to it.